# Python pandas functions work in shell not in script

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe in which I'm trying to run some operations on a column of string values which includes some missing data being interpreted as `float('nan')`, equivalent to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'otherData':[1,2,3,4],'stringColumn':[float('nan'),'Random string one... ','another string..  ','a third string    ']})
```

**`DataFrame` contents:**

```
otherData    stringColumn
1            nan
2            'Random string one... '
3            'another string..  '
4            ' a third string    '
```

I want to clean the `stringColumn` data of the various trailing ellipses and whitespace, and impute empty strings, i.e. `''`, for `nan` values.

To do this, I'm using code equivalent to:

```
df['stringColumn'] = df['stringColumn'].fillna('')
df['stringColumn'] = df['stringColumn'].str.strip()
df['stringColumn'] = df['stringColumn'].str.strip('...')
df['stringColumn'] = df['stringColumn'].str.strip('..')
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when I run this code in the script I've written, it doesn't work. There are still `nan` values in my 'stringColumn' column, and there are still some, but not all, ellipses. There are no warning messages. However, when I run the exact same code in the python shell, it works, imputing `''` for `nan`, and cleaning up as desired. I've tried running it in IDLE 3.5.0 and Spyder 3.2.4, with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works nicely for me on pandas `v0.20.2`, so you might want to try upgrading with

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

---

Call `str.strip` first, and you can do this in *one* `str.replace` call.

```
df.stringColumn = df.stringColumn.fillna('')\
        .str.strip().str.replace(r'((?<=^)\.+)|(\.+(?=$))', '')

0                     
1    Random string one
2       another string
3       a third string
Name: stringColumn, dtype: object
```

If `nan` is not a `NaN`type, but a string, just modify your regex:

```
((?<=^)\.+)|(\.+(?=$))|nan
```

---

**Regex Details**

```
(
(?<=^)    # lookbehind for start of sentence
\.+       # one or more '.'
)
|         # regex OR
(
\.+       # one or more '.'
(?=$)     # lookahead for end of sentence
)
```

The regex looks for leading or trailing dots (one or more) and removes them.

Comment: To clarify, you ran this in a script, not the shell, and it worked?

Comment: @ColeRobertson Uhm, yes.

Comment: Hmmmm. After the update, this works in a dummy script for me as well, but not in the real data. I'm sorry not to make the problem replicable, but if I knew how to do that, I'd likely know how to fix it as well... Any further suggestions?

Comment: @ColeRobertson See my edit about changing the regex for "nan" strings.

Comment: It's not a string, though. `isinstance(datapoint,float)` yields `True`.

Comment: @ColeRobertson I'm sorry but I really can't help without any more information than "it's not working for me".

Comment: @ColeRobertson Keep the discussion here please, I'm not frequent enough to come on chat.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm sorry. As I've said, if I knew how to make it replicable, I'd probably know the problem. Thanks for your help. I'll post if I come up with the solution.

Comment: I've solved it by creating a new column using the equivalent of  `df.stringColumnBeta = df.stringColumn.apply(str)` and then using, in the next line, your updated regex for dealing with strings without the `fillna()` function, e.g. `df.stringColumnBeta = df.stringColumnBeta.str.strip().str.replace(r'((?<=^)\.+)|(\.+(?=$))|nan', '')`. For some reason, this works but operating on the original column, e.g. `df.stringColumn = df.stringColumn.apply(str)` does not.

Comment: @ColeRobertson For dealing with string representations of "nan", use `((?<=^)\.+)|(\.+(?=$))|nan`, if you want to replace those too. I'm happy my answer helped (somewhat). Throw me an upvote or accept if you feel like it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me as well with `pandas==0.20.1`.

You can also do this as a one-liner without regexes. The `strip()` method supports a `chars` argument of characters to remove from both ends of the string.

```
df['stringColumn'] = df['stringColumn'].fillna('').str.strip('. ')
```

Docstring for `strip()`:

```
S.strip([chars]) -> str

Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing
whitespace removed.
If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

Comment: Yeah, it works for me as well. I think the problem was something to do with idiosyncrasies in the real data, which obviously I can't share, and how pandas was handling those.